# Troubling adding to a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to build a map with a custom comparator, however, something that I can not figure it out goes wrong, being unable to add item to the map (specifically, can only add the first item)

```
struct byKey
{
    bool operator () ( const Key &key1, const Key &key2) const {
        return key1.keytoInt() < key2.keytoInt();
    }
};
```

where Key class has a private char[5], like

```
char[0]=1, char[1]=2, char[3]=13, char[4]=20, char[5]=28
```

**there is a matching going that ensures all the character in char digit[5] (is less than 32) and can be converted to a character.like char=0, it will search a table, find a character like A**

I use a method in Key to covert it to int, then compare with int

```
int Key ::  keytoInt() const{
    int sum;
    sum=atoi(digit);
    return sum;
}
```

I build a table of map with key and value both as Key type, however, when trying to test it, I can not add items to the table, I am not sure where goes wrong.

**No compile error, however, logically, even though I have inserted into the map three times, the map.size() shows there is only one**

```
map<Key,Key,byKey> firstmap;  
map<Key,Key>::iterator it;
firstmap.insert(pair<Key,Key>(base,stepguess));
firstmap.insert(pair<Key,Key>(stepguess,base));
firstmap[stepguess]=base;
cout << "wait";
cout << "mymap.size() is " << firstmap.size() << '\n';
```

Comment: @avarookie Plese describe in words what function keytoInt has to do.

Comment: _'I am not sure where goes wrong.'_ What goes wrong, actually?? Compilation errors, unexpected behavior? Edit your question to give this information please.

Comment: Why don't you overload the operator< for your Key class. Then you don't have to specify a custom comparative for STL map.

Comment: It looks like the key characteristics have to be thought through again.  The behavior described so far implies using a `std::string` as the map key.  No more calls to `atoi` would be required, and the `struct byKey` goes away.  Also remember that the map can be sorted in ascending or descending order by using the `less <T>` or `greater<T>` in the third parameter of the map instance declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you're converting your key to an integer to compare that way, you're probably better off just comparing the fields directly. In this particular case, consider using `memcmp`, e.g.:

```
bool operator()(const Key& lhs, const Key& rhs) {
    return memcmp(lhs.digit, rhs.digit, sizeof(Key::digit)) < 0;
}
```

`atoi` in this case will always return 0 unless you have values which are valid ASCII digits (which these are not).

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what I know:

```
class Key {
    public:
        int keyToInt() const {
            return atoi(digit);
        }

    private:
        char digit[5];
};
```

You've also suggested, that there is an example `Key` that has:

```
Key k;
k.digit = {1, 2, 13, 20, 28};
```

In this case, you have 2 errors:

1. `digit` is not null terminated. So calling `atoi()` on it is undefined behavior.
2. The ascii characters in `digit` are not numbers, so you're going to get unhelpful results.

---

We can also build up a complete test case that shows that `std::map` is sane.

```
#include <map>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>

class Key {
    public:
        Key() {
            strncpy(m_digit, "0", 5);
            assert(m_digit[4] == '\0');
        }

        Key(const char *digit) {
            strncpy(m_digit, digit, 5);
            assert(m_digit[4] == '\0');
        }

        int keyToInt() const {
            return atoi(m_digit);
        }

    private:
        char m_digit[5];
};

struct byKey {
    bool operator () ( Key const & key1, Key const & key2) const {
        return key1.keyToInt() < key2.keyToInt();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<Key, Key, byKey> myMap;

    Key a("123");
    Key b("234");

    myMap[a] = b;
    myMap[b] = a;

    assert(myMap.size() == 2);
}
```

Comment: for error 2, there is a matching going that ensures all the character in char digit[5] (is less than 32) and can be converted to a character.like char=0, it will search a table, find a character like A so, it's not a bother

Comment: Without a compliable test case that you can show us, it will be difficult to diagnose your issue then. I've added an example of what that test case might look like.